# Prevent overlap of image views on touch and rotate

Tags: android, imageview

In the app that i am working on there are 2 separate image views in a relative layout. I want to have both images as movable and rotatable in response to the given action events the XML for my activity is:

```
<RelativeLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 tools:context="com.example.vishalbisht.dragfeature.MainActivity">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:id="@+id/Recycle"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/Ring"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

While the program part is :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnTouchListener {

ImageView jwl,rlo;
private final String TAG="DRAGFEATURE";
String Mode;
Bitmap bitmap,rotaBitmap;
BitmapDrawable bdr;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    jwl= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.Recycle);
    rlo= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.Ring);
    jwl.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon);
    rlo.setImageResource(R.drawable.ring);
    jwl.setOnTouchListener(this);
    rlo.setOnTouchListener(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    int eId = event.getActionMasked();
    Mode = "Move";
    switch (eId) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                Log.v(TAG,"move image");
                drag(v, event);
                break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                r = r + 13;
                rotate(v);
                break;
        default:break;
    }
    if (v != jwl && v != rlo)
        Log.v(TAG,"Not Valid");

    return true;
}

private int r =2;

private void rotate(View v) {
    if(v==jwl)
        bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.icon);
    else
        bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.ring);
    int w = bitmap.getWidth();
    int h = bitmap.getHeight();
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.preRotate(-r);
    rotaBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, w, h, matrix,true);
    bdr = new BitmapDrawable(rotaBitmap);
    if(v==jwl)
        jwl.setImageDrawable(bdr);
    else
        rlo.setImageDrawable(bdr);
}

private void drag(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams mParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) jwl.getLayoutParams();
    Log.v(TAG,"Start of Move");
    int x = (int) event.getRawX();
    int y = (int) event.getRawY();
    mParams.leftMargin = x - 150;
    mParams.topMargin = y - 210;
    if(v==jwl)
        jwl.setLayoutParams(mParams);
    else
        rlo.setLayoutParams(mParams);

 }
}
```

when i touch or drag the left image (Recycle) then its fine but when I click on Ring then the two images overlap and move/rotate together. Why is this happening and how to fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
        int pointerCount = event.getPointerCount();
        switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
//                downCounter++;
//                Log.v("","Action Down"+downCounter);

                startClickTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();

                dX = view.getX() - event.getRawX();
                dY = view.getY() - event.getRawY();

                final float rawX = event.getRawX();
                final float rawY = event.getRawY();

                // Remember where we started
                mLastTouchX = rawX;
                mLastTouchY = rawY;
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
//                moveCounter++;
//                Log.v("", "Action Move "+moveCounter);
                if (pointerCount == 1) {

                    final float x1 = event.getRawX();
                    final float y1 = event.getRawY();

                    // Calculate the distance moved
                    final float dx = x1 - mLastTouchX;
                    final float dy = y1 - mLastTouchY;

                    // Make sure we will still be the in parent's container
                    Rect parent = new Rect(0, 0, root.getWidth(), root.getHeight());

                    //Find what the bounds of view will be after moving
                    int newLeft = (int) (view.getX() + dx),
                            newTop = (int) (view.getY() + dy),
                            newRight = newLeft + view.getWidth(),
                            newBottom = newTop + view.getHeight();

                    if (!parent.contains(newLeft, newTop, newRight, newBottom)) {
                        Log.v("", "Out of Bounds");
                    } else {
                        // Move the object
                        view.animate().
                                x(x1 + dX).
                                y(y1 + dY).
                                setDuration(0).
                                start();
                        // Remember this touch position for the next move event
                        mLastTouchX = x1;
                        mLastTouchY = y1;
                        // Invalidate to request a redraw
                        root.invalidate();
                        break;
                    }
                }
//                if(mode==2)
                if (pointerCount == 2)
                {
                    long clickDuration = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() - startClickTime;
                    if(clickDuration > MAX_CLICK_DURATION) {
                        //Log.v(TAG, "for rotation");

                        float degree = rotation(event);

                        //Log.v(TAG, "setting at angle" + degree);

                        view.setRotation(view.getRotation() + degree);
                        break;

                    }
                }
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
//                upCounter++;
//                Log.v(TAG,"Action Up"+upCounter);


           /* case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                Log.v(TAG, "ACTION POINTER DOWN");
                if (pointerCount == 2) {
                    flagFirstTouch = 1;
                }
                break;*/

        }
        return true;
    }
```

I used this to sort my problem I hope this helps somebody.

Also, keep both the image views in separate frameLayouts inside the parent RelativeLayout.The frameLayouts can have attribute wrap_content for both height andwidth

Answer (score 0):

change your layout xml as below :

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:id="@+id/Recycle"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/Ring"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Recycle"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
```

Comment: I just tried your solution and while this is definitely better for moving the imageview id:Recycle i am still getting the same issue when I touch on Imageview id:ring or drag it.